# Getting errors trying to change the values of a column with conditions

Tags: pandas, numpy

Here's my data:

```
id  medianHouseValue  housingMedianAge  totalBedrooms  totalRooms  \
 0        23           113.903              31.0          543.0      2438.0   
 1        24            99.701              56.0          337.0      1692.0   
 2        26           107.500              41.0          123.0       535.0   
 3        27            93.803              53.0          244.0      1132.0   
 4        28           105.504              52.0          423.0      1899.0        households  population  medianIncome  
 0          481.0      1016.0        1.7250  
 1          328.0       856.0        2.1806  
 2          121.0       317.0        2.4038  
 3          241.0       607.0        2.4597  
 4          400.0      1104.0        1.8080
```

Here's what I'm trying to do:
change any values in the `medianIncome` column that are `0.4999` or lower to `0.4999` and change any values that are `15.0001` and higher to `15.0001`.

I've tried this:

```
housing.loc[housing[‘medianIncome'] > 15.0001, 'medianIncome'] = 15.0001
housing.loc[housing[‘medianIncome'] < 0.4999, 'medianIncome'] = 0.4999
```

And get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'loc'
```

So then I tried this:'

```
housing['medianIncome'] = np.where(housing['medianIncome'] >= 15.0001, housing['medianIncome'])
housing['medianIncome'] = np.where(housing['medianIncome'] <= 0.4999, housing['medianIncome'])
```

And get this error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I've looked up both errors but can't seem to find a solution that will accommodate. There's a lot more rows, it's just not letting me co[y/paste them all here and I can't recall how to upload the data set.

Comment: what does type(house) return?

Comment: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

Comment: medianIncome is coming up as a string but was supposed to be a float